# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am new to JPA. When I run the below program I am getting **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence has interface org.hibernate.ejb.AvailableSettings as super class**

I don't know how to proceed

hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final,hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.final.jar,
hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("hello-world");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction txn = em.getTransaction();
            try {
                txn.begin();

                Message msg= new Message("Hello World with Hibernate as JPA Provider");
                em.persist(msg);

                txn.commit();
            }   catch(Exception e) {
                    if(txn != null) { txn.rollback(); }
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }   finally {
                    if(em != null) { em.close(); }
            }
```

Comment: I am pretty sure `hibernate-core:5.2.12` does not require *any* version of `hibernate-entitymanager`

Comment: Thanks Crizzis. I have downloaded the hibernate-entitymanager-5.2.12.Final for hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final and now I am facing some different error. **org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"** . If I run the same program with same configuration in hibernate giving connection details in hibernate.cfg.xml its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception. It got solved after removing **hibernate-entitymanager-.final.jar** dependency.